# How to draw/fill any path around labels?

Tags: metapost, metafun

Is there any way to draw and/or fill any path around labels in MetaPost/MetaFun?

According to [the manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) (page 27) we can use `fill`/`unfill` with `bbox` and `thelabel`,  however there is nothing about, let's say, `label@#`.
I obviously tried the manual examples with `label@#` but it seems to fail.

Plus, I failed to correctly set a custom path (an ellipse, a star, a triangle, whatever) with `setbound.. to..` around the label to `draw`/`fill`.

```tex
fill unitsquare scaled 1cm xscaled 3 yscaled 3 withcolor gray ;
picture l ; l = thelabel(btex $A$ etex, (1cm,1cm));
unfill bbox l ; draw l ;
```

gives us

[image]

So I tried to set a "custom" circle around the label instead of the default `llcorner p--lrcorner p--urcorner p--ulcorner p--cycle`:

```tex
fill unitsquare scaled 1cm xscaled 3 yscaled 3 withcolor gray ;
picture l ; l = thelabel(btex $A$ etex, (1cm,1cm));
path b ; b = llcorner l..lrcorner l..urcorner l..ulcorner l..cycle ;
setbounds l to b ;
fill bbox l withcolor green ;
draw l ;
```

which does not return the expected result:

[image]

What is the correct way to do all of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want also with plain Metapost.  You were very nearly there but you just needed to make it a bit simpler:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
fill unitsquare scaled 1cm xscaled 3 yscaled 3 withcolor 1/2;
picture l; l = thelabel(btex $A$ etex, (1cm,1cm));
path b; b = llcorner l..lrcorner l..urcorner l..ulcorner l..cycle ;
fill b withcolor green ;
draw l;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

compile this with `lualatex` (or adapt for plain MP) to get this:

[image]

Your `b` path is circular as you expected, but `bbox b` is a square.  So all I have done differently is to fill `b` rather than `bbox b`.  The `bbox` macro always produces a square.  It also adds `bboxmargin` space around the path or image.  So you could have written

```
path b; b = for i=1 upto 4: point i of bbox l .. endfor cycle;
```

which would make a less tight circle, like this:

[image]

But in general it is probably easier to draw the shape you want first, then add a label to the center of it.  So you could have done:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    fill unitsquare scaled 1cm xscaled 3 yscaled 3 withcolor 1/2;
    path b; b = fullcircle scaled 16 shifted (1cm, 1cm);
    fill b withcolor green;
    label(btex $B$ etex, center b);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

which is a bit "cleaner" perhaps?  (Although you might have to guess at the diameter of the label with a bit of trial and error.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not so far away, but the `bbox` is always a rectangle. Here is an example, where I used `curved` to convert the bouding box. I also added one option with some randomness.

The wonderful [MetaFun manual](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) is full of nice things to pick up. Appendix C is very convenient when it comes to building and transforming paths. Have (Meta)Fun!

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
fill unitsquare scaled 1cm xscaled 3 yscaled 3 withcolor "darkgray" ;
picture l ; l := thelabel(btex $A$ etex, (1cm,1cm)) ;
path b ; b := curved boundingbox l  ;
fill b withcolor darkgreen ;
draw l ;
draw boundingbox l withcolor "orange" withpen pencircle scaled 0.1;

l := thelabel(btex $B$ etex, (2cm,2cm)) ;
b := (curved boundingbox l) 
     randomrotatedcontrols 1cm ;
fill b withcolor darkred ;
draw l ;
draw boundingbox l withcolor "orange" withpen pencircle scaled 0.1;
\stopMPpage
```

[image: circled A and B]